# How to inject data in tooltip

Tags: d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I'm using [angularjs-nvd3-directives](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/issues/201) to render my charts. I have an issue on a chart where I have 2 series, one of the serie has tooltip disabled using `chart.lines.interactive(false)` and the other serie has it enabled.

I want to display in the remaining tooltip the value of the other serie as well as the current serie. A little bit like this: http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html

With `angularjs-nvd3-directives` you have to specify the `tooltipContent` function that will render the tooltip. This function takes 5 parameters:

```
$scope.toolTipContentFunction = function() {
    return function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`graph` is the `chart` function that is returned by `nvd3`. I tried to get the data from it but I cannot find any methods to get it.

How could I do it ?

Maxime

Comment: What do you get when you try printing `key, x, y, e, graph` in the function ???

Comment: `key`: name of the current serie
`x`: Current `x` value of the serie
`y`: Current `y` value of the serie
`e`: mouseover event
`graph`: function returned by `nvd3`